# Regex to match 6 digits but no repeating

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that matches exactly 6 digits but fails for certain numbers.

This `/^\d{6}$/` works which matches 6 digits. But I want the following cases too:

```
123456 should fail
111111 should fail
222222 should fail
```

so any repeating digit should fail, so 3 conditions:

- Only 6 digits
- Is not 123456
- Is not repeating numbers

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?!012345|123456|234567|345678|456789|567890)(\d)(?!\1{5})\d{5}$`  https://regex101.com/r/g0ZDfW/1

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: What about `122345` where eg `2` is repeated?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this regex:

```
^(?!(\d)\1{5}|123456)\d{6}$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ptE1rC/2)

From the start of the string, we do a negative lookahead for repeating digits and 123456 sequence, after which we match six digits.

```
^                      # Line start
(?!                    # Negative lookahead
   (\d)\1{5}           # a digit and check that it does not repeat
   |                   # OR
   123456              # 123456 sequence
)   
\d{6}                  # Match 6 digits
$                      # End of line
```